# why isn't $number expanded in url="$number_foo"?

Tags: bash, variables

Using this code:

```
for i in {10000..99999}
do
    for j in {0..99999}
    do
        for k in {0..999}
        do
            number="$i$j$k"
            url="$number/$number_LNN_0001.png"

            wget mywebsite.com/$url
        done
    done
done
```

to get back my files from my server, it gives this strange output :

```
--2014-12-28 20:52:45--  http://www.mywebsite.com/1000000/.png
2014-12-28 20:52:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2014-12-28 20:52:45--  http://www.mywebsite.com/1000001/.png
2014-12-28 20:52:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I don't understand why it isn't `http://www.mywebsite.com/1000001/1000001_LNN_0001.png`

Comment: Note that you don't need quotes on the right-hand side of an assignment without any whitespace literals -- string-splitting and glob expansion are implicitly disabled -- but you *do* need it in other expansion contexts, such as when you're actually calling `wget`.

Comment: By the way -- you have two variables here at expansion time, `number` and `numbers`, but only one of those two is being set. Is that intentional?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy typo, going to correct it right know

Comment: How long do you think it will take to download 9 trillion files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
url=$number/${number}_LNN_0001.png
wget "http://mywebsite.com/$url"
```

Otherwise, the `_` (and succeeding characters) are parsed as part of the variable name. (This isn't necessary for the first `$number` as `/` isn't a valid character within shell variable names).

Comment: Well it output this `10000020/%7B10000020%7D_LNN_0001.png` using `url=$number/{$number}_LNN_0001.png`

Comment: `{$number}` is not `${number}`.

Answer (score 1):

Because this

```
$numbers_LNN_0001
```

makes a perfectly correct variable *name* in Bash - and it does not esist in your script.
If you want to combine variable values with other strings but without whitespaces around the variable, you will have to use `${NAME}`:

```
            url="$number/${number}s_LNN_0001.png"
```

More on variables: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

> The braces are required when parameter is a positional parameter with more than one digit, or when parameter is followed by a character that is not to be interpreted as part of its name.